# Float left и flaot right

Tags: css3, css

Верстаю шаблон со всеми фичами css3 и вот встретился уже с проблемой.
Если разрешение по ширине 1980 пикселей (как у меня), то все нормально. А если меньше - то все съезжает.

Пробовал "починить" сам - приводилось к тому, что была видна тень с прозрачным фоном.

- Тень с прозрачным фоном, где все
     нормально -
     http://bifot.ru/cloud/template2/
- Все нормально с фоном, но все съезжает - http://bifot.ru/cloud/template/

Надеюсь, объяснил понятно. Хотя, вы сами поймете, в чем беда, когда зайдете по ссылкам.

Comment: Ошибка 403, доступ к данной странице запрещен.

Comment: Попробуйте по http://bifot.ru/cloud/template2/index.html и http://bifot.ru/cloud/template/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы не съезжало при ваших данных нужно добавить в `css`:

```
#header {
  min-width: 1450px; // минимум 1445 у меня получается, на всякий случай добавил 5px
}
```